# How can i exclude "Y" from drag in unity?

Tags: unity

I'm trying to make a moving object drag when no input is received, but i want the drag to only apply to X and Z variables, and not Y. Meaning i want it to fall at a normal speed, but when i stop giving it force in x and z directions, i want it to gradually and quickly stop going in those directions. How can i achieve this?

I've done this:

```
Vector3 input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") , 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
If (input.x == 0 && input.z ==0) rb.drag = 3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Drag` of a `Rigidbody` is directed toward positive y-axis as it's supposed to be in a physical circumstances.

For moving and stopping a `Rigidbody` quick and gradually you should use it's `velocity` depending on `input`. As soon as there is no `input`, it will gradually stop.

Your code should be like:

```
void FixedUpdate()
{  
 Vector3 input = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));

 rigidbody.velocity = input * 10f;// * Time.fixedDeltaTime; // Increase the value if using fixedDeltaTime
}
```

Comment: Sorry for answering late. So you mean i shouldn't use AddForce, and should directly manipulate velocity?

Comment: I don't see where you want to use force. Usual case for `AddForce` is Jump. `Drag` is usually manipulated in case of air resistance or buoyancy. If you use force for movement, you will need an inverse force to stop it.

Comment: I'm building upon Roll a Ball tutorial, and that's why I'm using force. I will test the reverse force tomorrow, seems to do what i want. Just to be clear, with the code you wrote (rb.Velocity), my ball will stop immediately when no input is received, right?

Comment: it's immediate but take tiny bit of time to reach the input axis from +/1 to 0 so as the velocity. don't know what roll-a-ball tut does.